# Problemas com Foreach PHP para ler Json

Tags: php, json

Eu estou tentando pegar os valores dos itens (codigo e preco) como segue no Json abaixo:

```
 {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "message": "Ok",
      "description": "Requisição realizada com sucesso",
      "data": [
        {
          "nomePromocao": "teste de voucher",
          "dtaInicio": "2019-03-19T00:00:00",
          "itens": [
            {
              "codigo": "957",
              "preco": 9
            },
            {
              "preco": 0,
              "quantidade": 12
            },
            {
              "preco": 0
            },
            {
              "familia": 4,
              "preco": 12,
              "quantidade": 2
            }
          ]
        }, segue o próximo produto
   

{
  "nomePromocao": "Mês dos Achocolatados",
  "dtaInicio": "2019-03-31T00:00:00",
  "dtaFim": "2019-04-30T00:00:00",
  "itens": [
    {
      "codigo": "7896283514142",
      "preco": 12.3
    },
    {
      "codigo": "7891000387603",
      "preco": 11.2
    },
    {
      "codigo": "7894321711317",
      "preco": 11.3
    }
  ]
},
```

Meu código PHP:

```
$jsonStr = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

$nome = array();
$data = array();
$itens = array();

foreach(($jsonArr["data"]) as $valor){
    echo $nome[] = $valor["nomePromocao"] . '</br>';
    echo $data[] = $valor["dtaInicio"] . '</br>';
    echo $itens[] = $valor["itens"]["codigo"] . '</br>';
}
```

Nos itens ele me retorna um erro

> teste de voucher 2019-03-19T00:00:00
>
> Notice: Undefined index: codigo in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\promocao.php on line 20

qual o erro do meu foreach para chegar no codigo e nas outras informações?

Se eu tento assim:

```
foreach(($jsonArr["data"]) as $valor){
    echo $nome[] = $valor["nomePromocao"] . '</br>';
    echo $data[] = $valor["dtaInicio"] . '</br>';
    echo $itens[] = $valor["itens"][0]["codigo"] . '</br>';
    echo $itens[] = $valor["itens"][1]["preco"] . '</br>';
}
```

ele só trás o primeiro valor..não consigo avançar

Comment: Todos os itens tem código? O erro diz que algum item não tem o índice código.

Comment: Alguns não tem, mas por exemplo, logo abaixo tem um item que tem 3 códigos e só aparece o primeiro..vou atualizar minha pergunta

Comment: Você precisa de um `foreach` para percorrer `$jsonArr["data"]` e outro para percorrer `$jsonArr["data"][N]["items"]`... E me parece que você não precisa "reorganizar" a estrutura que veio da API, pois ela já está adequada. Você parece estar complicando a estrutura para fazer algo que você não explicou na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema acontece por dois motivos:

1. Porque você não está iterando os "itens", mas apenas o índice "data".
2. Porque o índice "código" não existe em todos os itens.

Para resolver o primeiro problema, deverá ser adicionado um segundo foreach para os "itens".

Para resolver o segundo problema, você deve verificar pela existência do índice "codigo" usando "isset()".

Você deverá modificar um pouco seu código para resolver isso:

```
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

$nome = array();
$data = array();
$itens = array();

foreach(($jsonArr["data"]) as $valor){

    $nome[] = $valor["nomePromocao"];
    $data[] = $valor["dtaInicio"];

    foreach($valor["itens"] as $indice => $item){
        if (isset($item["codigo"])) {
            $itens[] = $item["codigo"];
        }

    }

}

var_dump($nome, $data, $itens);
```

O resultado será:

```
/var/www/stackoverflow/question.php:54:
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'teste de voucher 1' (length=20)
  1 => string 'teste de voucher 2' (length=20)
/var/www/stackoverflow/question.php:54:
array (size=2)
  0 => string '2019-03-19T00:00:00' (length=21)
  1 => string '2019-03-19T00:00:00' (length=21)
/var/www/stackoverflow/question.php:54:
array (size=2)
  0 => string '957' (length=3)
  1 => string '959' (length=3)
```

Espero tê-lo ajudado!!

Comment: não rolou, não aparece mais nenhum código

Comment: aparece algum erro?

Comment: cara, agora vai da certo!